# Custom exception. This undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

I'm trying to create my own exception.
So i can format the error based on the environment the nodejs server is running. When the error is thrown this is undefined.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var states = require('../states');
  var env = states.config.env;
  var _   = require('underscore');

  /**
   * This is a error that is going to be thrown on server errors.
   * The application format the message for the specific environment
   * @param error The error
   */
  var unrecoverableError = function (error) {
    this.name = 'unrecoverableError';
    this.message = _.isEqual(env, 'production') ? 'There was a server error. Please contact server admin' : error.toString();
    this.code = 500;
  };

  unrecoverableError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
  unrecoverableError.prototype.constructor = unrecoverableError;

  module.exports = unrecoverableError;
}());
```

I also use sequelize as ORM.

```
organisation.findOne({
        where: {
          name: organisationName
        }
      })
        .then(function (organisation) {
          if (_.isEmpty(organisation)) {
            throw new modelNotFoundException();
          } else {
            resolve(organisation);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          if (error instanceof modelNotFoundException) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            throw new unrecoverableError(error);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          reject(error);
        });
```

Then in my console i get the error.

[TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined]

I can't figure out what i did wrong. It's working in the browser.
Here is a working fiddle example. https://jsfiddle.net/y3gk0hos/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because of the presence of the `"use strict";` statement which prevents 'illegal' access of the global environment.

If the function `unrecoverableError` is called without the `new` keyword, the `this` object would point to the global environment. While permitted in a browser, the `'use strict';` statement disallows this.

To ensure the `unrecoverableError` method instantiates an object, you'll need to check if it was executed without the `new` keyword and force the proper use:

```
var unrecoverableError = function (error) {
  // check if called with 'new'
  if (this instanceof unrecoverableError) {
    this.name = 'unrecoverableError';
    this.message = 'There was a server error. Please contact server admin';
    this.code = 500;
  }
  else {
    // method was not called with 'new'
    return new unrecoverableError(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm calling it with new right? Or am i understand you wrong. "throw new unrecoverableError(error);"

Comment: The solution works but i don't know if this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see why its important to only show the error message in the `production` environment.

Here is some code to follow for creating a custom error in Node:  https://gist.github.com/justmoon/15511f92e5216fa2624b  So refactor to match that format.

But that seem like it might be more work than its worth.  You can probably just do something like this: `throw new Error('Unrecoverable: ' + e.message)`.

Comment: Because i use custom errors to display an response. So a modelNotFoundException will give a 404. And i got a invalidParamsException that gives a 400. And all errors will be a unrecoverableError. The message is responded to the user. So i don't want a system error to be displayed to the user. Because its a system error so kind of useless for the user

Comment: OK if you want to use custom errors but I was talking about checking for prod/vs dev, in that one example it seems like it could just display the message in the console for dev/test as well as prod.  But that is a side issue.

Comment: Can you try changing your code to look more like that linked gist maybe?

Comment: I know. Trying to give you more context. Appreciate your thoughts

Comment: OK so yah try changing like that example but I reread your question and you are saying it is giving that TypeError only in Node.  I didn't see that before.  Is there some more code after what you showed that works with the organization model?  It looks like whatever code goes to load that organization, it fails to find it, and organization is undefined somewhere.

Comment: With Node I think you don't want/need to wrap that error module in a closure.

Comment: Yea i forced the error by providing wrong credentials for the database. And i followed the flow of the application. I get the sequelize error in the first catch. Than it goes into the unrecoverableError and the the error occures. So the promise catch going to fire. And than the express response.json gives a error to undefined cannot be toString() because error.message is undefined. When i console.log(this) in the unrecoverableError i get undefined. But the look alike code Works for my other exceptions. I currently not at my office anymore. So cannot try it at the moment

Comment: I have a index.js that requires all exceptions and errors so i can require that folder amd have all exceptions in One. And that Works normally. I never seen this kind of weird error